# microsoft login api: how to get code to exchange refresh_token

Tags: authentication, microsoft-graph-api, refresh-token, cross-origin-resource-policy

There are two steps in getting a refresh_token.
The first step is to get a code from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize endpoint.
The second step is to exchange the code you get from step 1 to get the refresh_token from the https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token endpoint.

If I set the type of redirect_uri to web on entra.microsoft.com, then the first step works, but the second step would return an error saying that: AADSTS90023: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application'.

If I set the type of redirect_uri to Single-page application on entra.microsoft.com, then the first step errors with error_description: Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption.

Any ideas to get the refresh_token from microsoft login?

Comment: set `http://localhost/myapp/` as redirect url in AAD web platform, and also use it in both of the requests

Answer (score 0):

After days of research, I finally found a package as a potential solution:
npm i @azure/msal-browser

[MSAL.js abstracts away all refresh token complexity and thus refresh tokens are not exposed by MSAL APIs by design.](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/48416e4ded23785856ad5c7ce918858b373f7bb4/lib/msal-browser/FAQ.md?plain=1#L336) When you need an access token please call the `acquireTokenSilent` API which will return to you a valid token from the cache or internally use the refresh token to acquire a new access token.

[Here is a code snippet:](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/48416e4ded23785856ad5c7ce918858b373f7bb4/samples/msal-node-samples/auth-code-cli-app/src/index.js#L36)

```
return pca.acquireTokenSilent(silentRequest).catch(e => {
  if (e instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
    return pca.acquireTokenInteractive(loginRequest)
  }
});
```